# Rails application information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to store some information about my rails application, like a version number. I am new to rails and I'm sure there is some sort of convention for doing this. What is the best method of doing this, maybe the environments file?

Comment: What are you going to use the information for? How you plan to use it has everything to do with the best way to store it.

Comment: It is simply for displaying the latest tag number from my repo to indicate the current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if it is 'best practice' but I also put mine in the environment.rb as a constant

and I am using SVN source control with a propset to update the revision number in the file upon checkin

```
# environment.rb
APPLICATION_VERSION = '1.3.0.$Revision: 203 $'
```

the only downside to this is that you must modify this file to get the revision to update, regular commits to other files will not cause the update

for display in the view

```
# application_helper.rb
def application_version
  return APPLICATION_VERSION.gsub('$Revision: ', '').gsub(' $', '')
end
```

kinda funky but it works

info on svn propset svn:keywords "Revision" - if interested?

http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/how-to-add-revision-number-id-automatically-to-subversion-files-in-two-simple-steps/